# Add data in array recursive php

Tags: php, recursion, array-push

I have a small problem, I have many directory which contains other directory and files. I would like to get all the directory names using a recursive way I have :

```
function getNomDossier($dir){
    $root = scandir($dir); //scanne le dossier
    $nom = [];
    foreach ($root as $value) {
        $variable = "$dir/$value";
        if ($value === '.' || $value === '..' || $value === '.DS_Store') {
            continue;
        }
        //on teste si c'est un dossier
        if (is_dir($variable)){
            array_push($nom, $value);
            getNomDossier($variable);

        }
    }

    return $nom;
}
```

When doing this I only have the first "scan", it doesn't go inside the directory to scan again and push into $nom...

Sorry if it's not clear and thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are checkig if $variable is a directory and then push $value in $nom
you just forget to push the value returned by getNomDossier to $nom. so to solve your problem replace:

```php
getNomDossier($variable);
```

with this:

```
$nom = array_merge($nom, getNomDossier($variable));
```

and the code should look like this:

```
function getNomDossier($dir){
    $root = scandir($dir); //scanne le dossier
    $nom = [];
    foreach ($root as $value) {
        $variable = "$dir/$value";
        if ($value === '.' || $value === '..' || $value === '.DS_Store') {
            continue;
        }
        //on teste si c'est un dossier
        if (is_dir($variable)){
            array_push($nom, $value);
            $nom = array_merge($nom, getNomDossier($variable));
        }
    }

    return $nom;
}
```